# change data value attr('data', 'value') not working correctly

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

I'm trying to add `data-name` to every parent div of images. I was trying:

```
<div><img src="..." alt=""/></div>
... 40 times (<div><img src="..." alt=""/></div>)
<div><img src="..." alt=""/></div>
```

js:

```
$("img").load(function() {
  $(this).parent().attr('data-name', 'abc')
});
```

On this way, only 1/3 of div was added. 2/3 above not. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try removing the `load()` handler, it is after all [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have problem to load so many images (some preloading will be better) you can just simply use:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
   $('img').parent().attr('data-name', 'abc');
})
```

Comment: How can I apply it with naturalWidth? $(this).parent().attr('data-size',  this.naturalWidth); Each of them has different size. Thx

Comment: I can not follow you. Do you mean that the images have different sizes and you want the parent div to expand to the image size. Or do you want the parent div to be all the same size and you want the images to fit them? You have posted a few lines of code in here so please explain.

Comment: I want the parent div to expand to the image size. (not all the same size) I was try: $("img").load(function() {
width = this.naturalWidth;
height = this.naturalHeight;
$(this).parent().attr('data-size', width+'x'+height)
});

Comment: Normally, the div containing the images will automatically get the size of the contained image. This is if you don't constrain in your 'CSS'  the width of the div to be fixed to a certain width. If you load the page what's happen at the moment?

Comment: Everything is showing correctly. But on PhotoSwipe they have defined attribute 'data-size', which is necessary to have. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: change this: $('img').parent().attr('data-name', 'abc'); to this: $('img').parent().attr('data-name', 'abc').attr('data-size', 'the size hier'). Please Don't forget to up vote the answer this is important to other user.

Comment: But I dont know how big is it. Attr 'data-size' is a size of currently image. (not all the same size)

Comment: This can also be done for every image that will be uploaded in the browser with: var height = $("img").height(); but this raise an other problem which imply that your code has to be changed. you need to loop for each loaded image and than set the attributes to the parent div. Not difficult to do at all. If you don't know how to do it and because this stack of comments become to long I advise you to re-post a new question for this. Maybe I will be the fist to see it and I can help you with this otherwise someone else will do. Believe me can be solved.

Comment: I am trying to make something for you, if this will not take much time I will post it here.

Comment: @TrungVu I have added an other answer for your new question use this and let me know. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your second question could be this one:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
     $('img').each(function(){
          var width = $(this).width();
          console.log(width)
          $(this).parent().attr('data-name', 'abc').attr('data-size', width);
     })
})
```

Note: I m checking here for the image width which I think will be the necessary one, if you need the height just change it.